# Python 3.3 - Paste dictionary to Excel

Tags: python, dictionary, paste, xlwt

I want to paste the following dictionary:

```
{'Olive Oil': 221.0, 'Ham - Pork': 216.14999999999998, 'Feta Cheese': 163.125, 'Vinegar': 5.1, 'Cherry Tomatoes': 22.5, 'Cucumber': 22.5}
```

in a new Excel Workbook:

```
newbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet = newbook.add_sheet('Table')
```

Using xlwt

Answer (score 1):

I used something similar to this. Hope this helps

```
import xlsxwriter

excelBook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
excelSheet = excelBook.add_worksheet()

elements = {'a':['e1','e2','e3'],
            'b':['e1','e2']
           } 
row = 0
col = 0

for key in elements.keys():
    row += 1
    excelSheet.write(row, col, key)
    for item in elements[key]:
        excelSheet.write(row, col + 1, item)
        row += 1

excelBook.close()
```

you could also use `DictWriter` (in csv).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works, but nevertheless I will look further for a simpler solution, like: sheet.paste(row,col,dictionary). Thanks!

Comment: @ViharChervenkov, look at my documentation, there is indeed a paste function: http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.Sheet.paste.html#pyexcel.Sheet.paste

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution if I could use my own [library](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which use xlwt-future indirectly:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> import pyexcel.ext.xls
>>> data={'Olive Oil': 221.0, 'Ham - Pork': 216.14999999999998, 'Feta Cheese': 163.125, 'Vinegar': 5.1, 'Cherry Tomatoes': 22.5, 'Cucumber': 22.5}
>>> data
{'Olive Oil': 221.0, 'Ham - Pork': 216.14999999999998, 'Vinegar': 5.1, 'Cherry Tomatoes': 22.5, 'Feta Cheese': 163.125, 'Cucumber': 22.5}
>>> v=[data.keys(), data.values()]
>>> v
[['Olive Oil', 'Ham - Pork', 'Vinegar', 'Cherry Tomatoes', 'Feta Cheese', 'Cucumber'], [221.0, 216.14999999999998, 5.1, 22.5, 163.125, 22.5]]
>>> sheet=pe.Sheet(v)
>>> sheet
Sheet Name: pyexcel
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+----------+
| Olive Oil | Ham - Pork | Vinegar | Cherry Tomatoes | Feta Cheese | Cucumber |
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+----------+
| 221       | 216.150    | 5.100   | 22.500          | 163.125     | 22.500   |
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+----------+
>>> sheet.transpose()
>>> sheet
Sheet Name: pyexcel
+-----------------+---------+
| Olive Oil       | 221     |
+-----------------+---------+
| Ham - Pork      | 216.150 |
+-----------------+---------+
| Vinegar         | 5.100   |
+-----------------+---------+
| Cherry Tomatoes | 22.500  |
+-----------------+---------+
| Feta Cheese     | 163.125 |
+-----------------+---------+
| Cucumber        | 22.500  |
+-----------------+---------+
>>> sheet.save_as("myfile.xls")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works, but nevertheless I will look further for a solution that doesn't require extra packages. If I can't find anything better, I will accept your answer.